# Python Calculator Code

Tags: python, calculator

I'm fairly new to python and have tried to develop a calculator. I have created it so that it keeps asking you questions until you press 9 and exits. I have made an error while doing this and it keeps asking me to enter first number and keeps looping that

```
loop = 1
oper = 0

while loop == 1:    
    num1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    print num1

    oper = input("+, -, *, /,9: ")
    print oper

    num2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print num2

    if oper == "+":
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif oper == "-":
        result = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif oper == "*":
        result = int(num1) * int(num2)
    elif oper == "/":
        result = int(num1) / int(num2)
    elif oper == "9":
        loop = 0


    print "The result of " + str(num1) + str(oper) + str(num2) + " is " + str(result)

    input("\nPress 9 to exit.")
```

Comment: fix indentation please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had problem with indentation and here's a better way to exit using break for the while loop:

```
loop = 1
oper = 0

while loop == 1:

    x = input("Press 9 to exit otherwise anything to continue:")#much better way
    if x == "9":
        break
    num1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    print (num1)

    oper = input("+, -, *, /: ")
    print (oper)

    num2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (num2)

    if oper == "+":
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif oper == "-":
        result = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif oper == "*":
        result = int(num1) * int(num2)
    elif oper == "/":
        result = int(num1) / int(num2):
    else:
       print("Invalid operator!") #if user inputs something else other than those


    print ("The result of " + str(num1) + str(oper) + str(num2) + " is " + str(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you never do anything to break in the first place. Try changing your `oper` to include `9`:

```
oper = raw_input("+, -, /, *, or 9 (to exit)": )
```

Then include an `elif` statement and change `loop` to 0 to exit the `while` loop:

```
elif oper == "9":
    loop = 0
```

Also, deal with your indention:

```
loop = 1

while loop == 1:    

    num1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    print num1

    oper = input("+, -, *, /,9: ")
    print oper

    num2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print num2

    if oper == "+":
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
    elif oper == "-":
        result = int(num1) - int(num2)
    elif oper == "*":
        result = int(num1) * int(num2)
    elif oper == "/":
        result = int(num1) / int(num2)
    elif oper == "9":
        loop = 0


print "The result of " + str(num1) + str(oper) + str(num2) + " is " + str(result)
```

Comment: Should be "loop = 0", shouldn't it? Loop = 1 will cause it to keep looping.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes it is

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you haven't indented. Python cares about how much you indent, and thus only indented lines will be considered part of the while loop. Here only the first line (`num1 = input...`) is being considered part of the while loop. The simplest way to fix this would be to add four spaces before each line that is supposed to be in the loop (as well as an additional four spaces before each line in an `if` statement).

See http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html for more help.

Comment: The indention *here* is incorrect but the OP mentions no error. The OP's problem here is how to exit the loop

Comment: But the lack of `break` isn't the problem, because he sets `loop = 0` and the loop condition is `while loop == 1`, so it should break. He says that only the first line of the loop is ever reached, which suggests to me that it is the only line treated as part of the loop (perhaps his Python interpreter works that way instead of giving an error).

Comment: i bet lines num1 = input(... and print num1 are indented but not the others,  so it only loops asking the first number, well maybe even only line num1 = input( ... is